# Class implements type with generic method but does not conform to the type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wish I had a more minimal example of the issue here. This is pretty short, but I can't seem to reproduce this issue without using type logic over tuples.

I'm defining types for a key-value store where keys can be tuples.

```
type Key = (string | number)[]
type KeyValuePairs = [Key, any]
```

Here's an example schema.

```
type Schema = 
    | [["a", number], number]
    | [["b", string], string]
```

I want to be able to define the database interface separate from the class so that there can be different backends / implementation.

```
type KeyValueStoreApi<S extends KeyValuePairs> = {
    get: <T extends S[0]>(key: T) => Extract<S, {0: T}>[1]
}
```

That return type appears to be what is causing me trouble as we'll see later. Anyways, I have an implementation of this type with a class:

```
class KeyValueStore<S extends KeyValuePairs> implements KeyValueStoreApi<S> {
    get<T extends S[0]>(key: T): Extract<S, {0: T}>[1] {
        return {} as any
    }
}
```

It's the EXACT same type interface...

Thus functions in my program references the type rather than the class so that the implementations are interchangeable.

```
function f(db: KeyValueStoreApi<Schema>) {}
```

But typescript is unhappy.

```
const db = new KeyValueStore<Schema>()
f(db) // TypeError
```

Here's the error:

```
Argument of type 'KeyValueStore<Schema>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyValueStoreApi<Schema>'.   The types returned by 'get(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>[1] | Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>[1]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>[1] & Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>[1]'.
      Type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>[1]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>[1] & Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>[1]'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>[1] & Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>[1]'.
          Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>[1]'.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
              Type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>[1]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>[1]'.
                Type 'Extract<[["a", number], number], { 0: T; }>' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>'.
                  Type '{ 0: T; } & [["a", number], number]' is not assignable to type 'Extract<[["b", string], string], { 0: T; }>'.(2345)
```

In fact, the class doesn't conform at all even though it's implementing the type!

```
const store: KeyValueStoreApi<Schema> = new KeyValueStore<Schema>() // same error
```

Any ideas what's going wrong here and how to fix it?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIHUFMHICdrgCbQGYEsB22Dm4AXATwAdoBncNAe3nAENwBraIgWgDd6AbAVyXIFaSAO4ALaImatKAY3pZwAIyQFeJbhQB0wYmXABpVuAC84ABSD4ecAB9wWXgFsV8AJQBtALq7SSI0QAajz8AAr0GPCUZh4BADQMWEQ+oBAAEpJwlArg0AAe9E4aArISTvQ6ekgAyqXQ5abgwACQ9h4eAET0HQmOLpJevc6uPq3g7R1KPeBWeIMzBNZYuClgUKIKBITUKOjYqhIo9AT0SvTkSNgEkmj0sgLQJPTwx0ho8NROhIey3OeU5B2BDEx2+mXA8iwqWUSGQGDQaEyWC2Z1kLCwyEoEAwRU0TmgyOOGGoWEqfkMrGCfGg1SEiAAgiQMAAeaq5PLXDGUAJUsIRKIAPkaAG8WrhoAQAFzgZkAFXZnMx4GqHgADF4BeYWERpbK3KYhQBRDkvWQEVkJYWq3UAXwFHgAjD4bcBgL9-hSgiEaXToKyFQSlTzveFIuQhTjivjkdzKd7acJGSzqkLRc1xeb5flFZQVerNdrdW5pcbFndzdVLdbwLK7Y6vOA081EGp4IphTaGNkki0XS7obKxLxKNReHRuNRcBhZOBEIjEFh7pRgapyS8V3RgTkVxC-uQAUCQVsd5G8QSTgRiVhslIrpJSgpxadNDo0LxF5eSVRzMglNLg9SCYMkyrJ1OUAr6h2rprAAQrwx5+OQsjWCQWwYJQ74giQJBEDosgkoIKBKI0WDQCInq8j6wigWU9Cam4wBoD+SgMdCACSii3GaCQrkQKAkrAWz4VgNDwF80AcAS3yjrgYjgBgBCUKe9TntAyDKHxO7UBueEEVsgjCP+caAb6SY0fUdEkWRFHxr65ngeYDFAA)

---

**Edit 1**

I've been able to reproduce this issue using objects instead of tuples: [playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIHUFMHICdrgCbQGYEsB22Dm4AXATwAdoBncNAe3nAENwBraIgWgDd6AbAVyXIFaSAO4ALaImatKAY3pZwAIyQFeJbhQB0wYmXABpVgDUe-cAF5wAbxZEAXAyxEANOC59ojhUQC+wUAgACUk4SgVwaAAPegBbDQFZCVj6HT0kAGUk6BTLcGAASAAfGztHAEY3D35HLF5YlXh-YtLWRwAmKrMvcEF4PH9AqFEFAkJqFHRsVQkUegJ6JXpyJGwCSTR6WQFoEnp4eaQ0eGpYwlnZbmXKcgmCMXnz0PB5LCGVFAw0NFCsMaXZCwsMhKBAMPFNLFoH95hhqFg0qQkEYiKZPBkhIgAIIkDAAHgykSi62BlBRaP4AD48tZCrhoARHHiACpEkkg8AZADaACI7DyALqUgAUZXAzIAlJZqQBRYkHWQEAluWxtcW+Sm86rQQXAQaXa6GEzdDHCAls6Ec8ndanghJQv5k43ozHQHH4jLU2kFelK1nRdmUbl81iCkViyWOOUEBVKjIqiMarXdQU2QoFRBqeCKay+BjhZyFfyDMDisS8SjUXh0bjUXAYWTgRA-RBYbaUe6qJFN+YSOj3CKdl5Xcg3O4PMZDu2Q6ELAhwrDhKRrSRJBT0xaaHRoXht+fwqjC5BKRzWl3Cd0E7IpSlS3MBUsAIV4k6R5Fk-RIYwwlF3DxIJBEDosjwoIKBKHkWDQCIRqoiarpXsk9AihKwBoEeSioUMACSiibIqbidkQKDwrAYwgVgNDwGc0AcNC5xVrgYjgBgBCUNOOSztAyDKMRQ7UJ28DAaBYyCMIp7OvwprYriiE5MhkHQbBFLQNJ0ByTewqoUAA). But it hasn't been too insightful really.

The main thing I've noticed is that if I get rid of the `[1]` part:  `Extract<S, {0: T}>[1]` → `Extract<S, {0: T}>`, then I don't have any type errors... Pretty annoying though, because I need that to properly specify the type...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Though I could use help coming up with the language to describe the problem... I stumbled upon this solution with guess-and-check. I found [this article](https://davidgomes.com/pick-omit-over-union-types-in-typescript/) and tried something similar using

```
type DistributiveProp<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends unknown
    ? T[K]
    : never;
```

Then I replaced `Extract<S, {0: T}>[1]` with `DistributiveProp<Extract<S, {0: T}>, 1>`. No idea why it worked honestly... Thoughts?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIEkHIFtwCYFMBmBLAdpg5uALgJ4AOSAzuCgPYBO4AhuANZIEC0AbnQDYCuS4pPDSQA6YIRLgA0iwBq3PuAC84AN7MCALnoYCAGnCdeSbXV0BfYKAgAJJNSTRyZ8EgAedWES79SAYwALJFg6MQl+AGVA4IYVYABIAB81DW0ARgMjPm0MHlgAI3tLJJSWbQAmTIUTATxqHEsrcPAAETRBevyePDR2JAAFakoiAB4AFQMpVzc8JAwEcg1KFHAxgD5lVenZ+fIeDEYMSgB3DGBwC-AAflWAbSkAXXPLnKQ+6gBuKzBwAHV+Y5mPD4SiIVCYfh4IKIOh4Oj5OikfiYWbUFB0Py+JBEOjUWH8FBDeBQ-h+LiI8ikUFQ2H4IIOcB+MzWcCFRBoFAoexzYEIvzMXbgCBoLw+WA82FoSgYMLEfgyAjyYwRIQOACCRDQIwi2zmC2kcmqGxUqgS2CQeG0411goitwARBp7Q81gAKVKrACUyg2bQ6aC6PT6g2GIwAojM8X48NqDOoyqtzGsDPaskh7WtgI0yRSDYrqirhNqbfqFUq+BsRd5gjzyGWC6qkBqtRENqb4uaY2MS+Q7Y6WM63R6xp7tH66gHur0BkNRhG6hiYxE48Ok3pU9UM+34g48DxqBg1OZ6M5dAlLI0WWMAjxSAZKPvwFxKNg0H5wA4uQ4MJjyCT8HKH6wvSdIuP+OakJS1IBLS-5VmKEo9NKzgMii9iBGY5rwj4YgoPs0ZSoeKCugg+TaPWyqNs22rRCEazeqojQ-AAQt0AEkP49REMC7TgPsMFEEQBBiH4yHAqRmwYEgxx5uWSCFg4NFBHRrqesAxGkWpLKQERi4GCSBCINK0DAqJGBUNQ8BvHMdIPtgATgGgeDkPBNYYLMCCsoZ-6UCS1AiWJtTCORhqUcI1FRMpdDGuAUkyRRfAKUgSkxG6WksWxTngMcNCMC5KzHPwCDGcCt6kuSkFkCI1XqfhSGHn4Dj4gl8mNsW7g7KWoUVqpIX5mF6qatqbYJLu+6HtunbWh1eq9g6Touu6CYjto85RkuK7LUmDpps6agJPEO4WuNR4njoBAHcUF5WGZgiIPk5SbI1SDNd1rVFpFqWqepJEPVpwBAA)